# How to insert zero elements in sparse matrix using shell, bash, awk, sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk, sparse-matrix

I need to insert the zero elements in any sparse matrix in the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html) format (but already without the headers).

The first column is the number of the ROW, the second columns is the number of the COLUMN and the third column is the VALUE of the element.

I'm using a 2 x 3 matrix for testing it. But i need to be able to do this to any dimension matrix, m x n.

The number of rows, columns and non-zero elements of each matrix are already in separated variables.

I've used bash sed and awk to work with these matrices until now.

Input file:

```
1 1 1.0000
1 2 2.0000
2 1 4.0000
2 2 5.0000
2 3 6.0000
```

ROWS and COLUMNS are integer %d and VALUES are float %.4f

Here only one element is zero (row 1 column 3), the line that represents it is omitted.

So, how can i insert this line???

Output file:

```
1 1 1.0000
1 2 2.0000
1 3 0.0000
2 1 4.0000
2 2 5.0000
2 3 6.0000
```

An empty 2 x 3 matrix would be like this:

```
1 1 0.0000
1 2 0.0000
1 3 0.0000
2 1 0.0000
2 2 0.0000
2 3 0.0000
```

Another example, a 3 x 4 matrix with more zero elements.

Input file:

```
1 2 9.7856
1 4 4.2311
2 1 3.4578
2 2 45.1231
2 3 -12.0124
3 4 0.1245
```

Output file:

```
1 1 0.0000
1 2 9.7856
1 3 0.0000
1 4 4.2311
2 1 3.4578
2 2 45.1231
2 3 -12.0124
2 4 0.0000
3 1 0.0000
3 2 0.0000
3 3 0.0000
3 4 0.1245
```

I hope you can help me. I already spent more then 3 days with trying a solution.

The best i got was this:

```
for((i=1;i<3;i++))
do
    for((j=1;j<4;j++))
    do
        awk -v I=${i} -v J=${j} 'BEGIN{FS=" "}
                            {if($1==I && $2==J)
                                    printf("%d %d %.4f\n",I,J,$3)
                            else
                                    printf("%d %d %d\n",I,J,0)
                            }' ./etc/A.2
        done
done
```

But its not efficient and prints lots of non desired lines:

```
1 1 1.0000
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 2 2.0000
1 2 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
1 3 0
1 3 0
1 3 0
1 3 0
1 3 0
2 1 0
2 1 0
2 1 4.0000
2 1 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 2 0
2 2 0
2 2 5.0000
2 2 0
2 3 0
2 3 0
2 3 0
2 3 0
2 3 6.0000
```

Please! Help me! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the max "I" and "J" values:

```
# cat tst.awk
{ a[$1,$2] = $3 }
END {
    for (i=1;i<=I;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=J;j++)
            print i, j, ( (i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : "0.0000" )
}

$ awk -v I=2 -v J=3 -f tst.awk file
1 1 1.0000
1 2 2.0000
1 3 0.0000
2 1 4.0000
2 2 5.0000
2 3 6.0000
```

If you'd rather the tool just figures it out (won't work for an empty file or if the max desired values are otherwise never populated):

```
$ cat tst2.awk
NR==1 { I=$1; J=$2 }

{
    a[$1,$2] = $3
    I = (I > $1 ? I : $1)
    J = (J > $2 ? J : $2)
}

END {
    for (i=1;i<=I;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=J;j++)
            print i, j, ( (i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : "0.0000" )
}

$ awk -f tst2.awk file
1 1 1.0000
1 2 2.0000
1 3 0.0000
2 1 4.0000
2 2 5.0000
2 3 6.0000
```

Comment: Works like a charm! That was the only missing part in my code. Now i can run it. Thank you very much!

I would like to understand better

a[$1,$2] = $3

and

(i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : "0.0000"

Comment: `a[$1,$2] = $3` just saves the 3rd field in an array indexed by the first 2 fields. `(i,j) in a` checks whether or not an entry exists in `a` indexed by the current `i` and `j` loop values, and `(i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : "0.0000"` prints the value of the array indexed by `i,j` if it does exist, otherwise it prints `0.0000`.